# Matlab: access files relative to working directory

Tags: matlab

I've noticed that most Matlab functions that acess files, e.g. `load()` resolve relative paths by finding some directory on the current path that contains files or directories matching these paths. E.g. calling `load('foo/bar.m')` will load `/home/someuser/dir1/foo/bar.m` over `/home/someuser/dir2/foo/bar` if the current working directory is `/home/someuser/dir2` but `/home/someuser/dir1` is on the search path.

I find this to be highly irritating and error-prone, how can I access files relative to the current working directory instead?

Comment: Did you try prefacing the releative path with the `./`to indicate it is relative? That works for me. Also the relative paths can be added with `addpath` if many accesses are needed, but that is prone to the shadowing you describe.

Comment: Yes, using `./` works, I didn't know about that, thanks!

Comment: Also potentially useful for you (or someone else) might be using .. to refer to the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, Matlab can resolve both relative and absolute paths. But my suggestions to handle your issue with less headaches:

1. At each (relevant/main) script ensure that your workspace is the scripts location with:

`PATH.SCRIPT = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'))
 cd(PATH.SCRIPT)`

2. Then, always call functions with absolute paths using:

`load([PATH.SCRIPT, filesep, 'filename'])`
or
`load([PATH.SCRIPT, filesep, '..' , filesep, 'file_at_upper_dir_name'])`
or
`load([PATH.SCRIPT, filesep, 'subfolder' , filesep, 'file_at_lower_dir_name'])`

3. If possible, try not messing too much with Matlab's default path, and at initialization of your workspace call `restoredefaultpath`. This reduces chances that there is a spurious folder in your path where name collisions can happen.
4. As others have mentioned, `./` or `['.', filesep]` also provides with with the current folder.
5. As @CrisLuengo mentions, instead of `filesep` one might prefer to compose paths with `fullfile`, for instance: `load(fullfile(PATH.SCRIPT, '..', 'file_at_upper_dir_name'))`

Comment: I'm not sure `cd` is a good suggestion. It is always confusing to your users when the current path changes from underneath them. But using absolute paths is always good. Did you know about `fullfile`? I think it's easier to use and clearer than concatenating with `filesep`. For example `load(fullfile(PATH.SCRIPT, 'subdir1', 'subdir2', 'filename'))`.

Comment: To find a path relative to current directory use `pwd`: `fullfile(pwd,'subdir1','filename')`.